# How to implement Time/(Distance)^2 in solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr5

I want to implement `Time/Distance^2` in solr. e.g.:

user locality is : BTM

**Question1:** posted 5hrs before. and distance from my locality is 2kms :5/4=1.25

**Question2** posted 2hrs before. and distance from my locality is 4kms: 2/16=0.125

**Question3** posted 4hrs before. and distance from my locality is 3kms : 4/9:0.44

Now when I fire the solr query, Results should come in the following order based on `T/D^2` formula:

```
question1 then question3 and question1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function query. See [FunctionQuery](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)

You could order by the function.
Use the functions div and pow.

```
sort=div(Time/pow(Distance,2)) asc
```

or

```
sort=div(Time/pow(Distance,2)) desc
```

You may add the function to the field list to debug the function:

```
fl=*,div(Time,pow(Distance,2))
```